# Get an error after deploying war file of grails Websocket using jar library

Tags: java, grails

Following code works fine in the development environment but not in production. I got stuck due to this. I have tried to deploy with tomcat v9.0.24 and Tomcat v8.5.32. In the development environment, tomcat v9.0.24 is working but the issue is with production.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerConfiguration.<init>()
```

grails-3.3.4 Gradle:

```
    //*********** Websoket *************//
    compile 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-server:1.13.1'
    compile 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-server:1.13.1'
```

1. Websocket class

```
    import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
    import grails.util.Environment
    import grails.util.Holders
    import pawnshoprest.staff.User

    import javax.websocket.*
    import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint

    @ServerEndpoint(value = "/broadcast/{user_id}/{username}")
    class WebSocketsService {
        //**************** declare client ***************
        private static Set<Session> clients = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

        @OnOpen
        static void onOpen(Session session) {
            System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());
            clients.add(session);
        }

        @OnMessage
        static String onMessage(String message, Session session){
            println("\n")
            System.out.println("my Message: " + message);
            synchronized(clients){
                // Iterate over the connected sessions
                // and broadcast the received message
                for(Session client : clients){
                    //if (!client.equals(session)){
                        System.out.println("************** Session ID *******************");
                        System.out.println("sender: " + session.getId());
                        System.out.println("Reciever: " + client.getId());
                        //************ broadcast message **********************
                        if(!session.pathParameters.user_id.equals(client.pathParameters.user_id)){
                            println('message sent to ' + client.pathParameters.username)
                            client.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
                        }
                    //}
                }
            }
            //return message;
        }

        @OnClose
        static void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
            //******** Client Disconnect ****************
            System.out.println("Disconnected ... " + session.getId());
            clients.remove(session)
        }
    }
```

2. Bootstrap.groovy

```
class Bootstrap{
       def init = { servletContext ->
           Server server = new Server("${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()}", 8025, "/websockets", null, WebSocketsService);
         try {
                server.start();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                println('\n')
                println('**************************** Socket running ****************************')
                println("Please press a key to stop the server.");
                println('\n')
                reader.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                println('\n')
                println('**************************** Socket Has Been Stopped ****************************')
                println('\n')
            }
      }
    }
```